# Lebesgue Diffrentiation

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be Lebesgue integrable in $[a,b]$ (with respect to Lebesgue measure of course). We want to show that there exist an antidrivative function $F$ which is absolutely continuous.

On my try to show that I took $F(t) = \int_a^t f(x)dm(x)$, and its easy to show that $F$ is absolutely continuous, but when i try to show that $F$ is diffrentiable I want to use the normal definition which is $F'(x) =\lim (1/h) (F(x+h) - F(x))$ when $h\rightarrow0$, but when i want to use Lebesgue diffrentiation theorem i cant do that because in the theorem i need an open set which $x$ contained in, and here $x$ is left\right limit of the interval, is there a way to use the theorem here that?

Comment: The Lebesgue differentiation theorem just gives you differentiability almost everywhere. In particular, if you skip the endpoints you don't lose anything.

Comment: Does that mean that the definition can be changed from open sets that contains $x$ to just sets that contains $x$?
how can i justify that?

Comment: could you post, which Lebesgue Differentiation theorem you want to apply? Where does it state that you need an open set? The Lebesgue differentiation theorem statest that $F'(x)=f(x)$ for a.e. $x\in[a,b]$. For the proof, fix some $x\in(a,b)$ Now you need to choose $h$ small enough, i.e. $h<\min(x-a,b-x)$. For the negative difference quotient one can argue similarly. However, the convergence only holds in a.e. $x\in[a,b]$. Since atoms are sets of measure zero, in you examination of the points $x$ you may neglect finitely many (also infinitely many) points

Comment: I guess in our class the prof decided to teach it with open sets containing x that shrink.
My problem is that i dont understand how i can switch from open sets to close sets that shrink to x and x is one of the bounderies.

Comment: You can also use relative open sets. If your domain is e.g. $[a,b]$ the sets $[a,c)$ are relatively open. However, the boundary points are not relevant for integration (if functions are integrable). Furthermore, one will only expect, that $F$ is differentiable a.e. (think of $f(x)=\mathrm{sign}(x)$). Can you show the a.e. differentiability away from the boundary values?